# iPhone App Update

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have an application on the Apple Store and would like to update the same.

In case something is broken, is there a definite way to revert to the previous version? I know after reading some of the posts it is not possible.

Someone suggested to get the IPA file via iTunes and then change the CFbundle version and repackage the IPA file. Below are the steps I used to re-sign the app
- Rename the iPA to ZIP.
- In the Payload, .APP -> Show Package contents
- Modify the info.plist file (CFBundle version and other similar string)
- Rezip the contents
- Rename the iPA file.

Is that all I have to do? Or have I missed anything.

But not sure if this is going to work. Unfortunately I do not have the source code for the version currently on the App Store (I have but not sure which was used for upload - proably not rightly tagged in repository).

Regards,

Nirav

Comment: Say for example version 1.0 was fine.. 1.1 had bugs and you want to revert it back to 1.0? I would suggest you make another update 1.2 in bundle id version with same code that was there in 1.0.

Comment: Yes exactly. In case 1.1 has bugs, how do I simply upload the same binary without compiling, but changing the version bundle id. Can it be done if I do not have the right code that was used to compile the binary currently sitting on the app store i.e 1.0 ?

Comment: Answer is NO. You can't becuase xcode's windows -> organizer does things which are not available for developers to see before it makes a binary and uploads the app to the app store.

Comment: Thanks John !! In case the app was sign using ad-hoc profile, in that case it would be possible right ?

Comment: Even if you have version 1.0 ipa file (and NOT the source code as you mentioned in your question) and version 1.1 is there in the app store, then its not possible to revert it back to 1.0 in the app store. Your 1.0 version app will be installed only on the devices whose UDID is there in the ad-hoc profile.